# Where to put website files in Bitnami LAMP Ubuntu server

Tags: apache, lamp, bitnami

Wheres the default folder in Bitnami LAMP? The server is running but I dont know where to put my html files? I mean in comparison with XAMPP and WAMP, the default is you put it on xampp/htdocs/ or wamp/www/.

I've tried using the /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/ and it works but I don't know if thats the default folder to put my website files in LAMP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that is the default folder for your HTML or PHP files. You can also add applications on top of Bitnami LAMP and they will be installed at /opt/bitnami/apps/ folder.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Really helped!

Answer (score 0):

HTML and program files on my AWS Bitnami server are in:

```
/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
```

Config file httpd.conf it's in:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf
```

Comment: /home/bitnami/apps is a symlink to /opt/bitnami/apps, that's why you can also find the WordPress' files inside the home folder of the bitnami user.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and php files, Bitnami on Google Cloud Platform server are in

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs
```

Config file httpd.conf in

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf
```

Answer (score 0):

On my cloud.google.instance it was:

```
/opt/bitnami/wordpress
```